# Solving pseudo arithmetic-geometric sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series

Let $p \in \mathbb{R}$ and $u_0 = 1$.

$$\forall k\in \mathbb{N}, u_{k+1} = (-2p+1)u_k + (p-2)(-1)^k$$

I would like to get an explicit formula for $u_k$.

Classical arithmetic-geometric sequences in the form $u_{k+1} = a u_k + b$ can be solved using the property that $u_{k+1}-u_k$ is a geometric sequence. But this doesn't work well since the $b$ term here depends on $k$.

I have similar problem with the following sequence, $v_{k+1} = (-2p+1)v_k - p(-1)^k$ with $v_0=0$.

The two sequences satisfy the coupled relations :
$$u_{k+1} = -(p+1)u_k-(p-2)v_k$$ 
$$v_{k+1} = -pu_k-(p-1)v_k$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$ u_{k+1} = (1 - 2p)u_k + (p-2)(-1)^k $$

let $$  A(x) =\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} u_{k}x^{k} = u_0 + \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} u_kx^k  = 1 + \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} u_kx^k$$

$$ = 1 + (1-2p)x\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} u_{k-1}x^{k-1} - (p-2)\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} (-x)^k$$

$$ = 1 + (1 - 2p)xA(x) + \frac{x(p-2)}{x + 1} \Rightarrow A(x) = \frac{1 + \frac{x(p-2)}{x+1}}{1 - x + 2px} = \frac{x+1 +x(p-2)}{(x+1)(1 + (2p-1)x)}$$

By partial fractions $$ A(x) = \frac{\frac{p-2}{2(p-1)}}{x+1} + \frac{\frac{p}{2(p-1)}}{1 + (2p-1)x}  = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{p-2}{2(p-1)}(-1)^k x^k + \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{p(1-2p)^k}{2(p-1)} x^k$$

$$ = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \left(\frac{p-2}{2(p-1)}(-1)^k + \frac{p(1-2p)^k}{2(p-1)} \right) x^k $$

$$ \Rightarrow u_k = \frac{p-2}{2(p-1)}(-1)^k + \frac{p(1-2p)^k}{2(p-1)}  $$

Answer (score 0):

$$
u_k = u_0(1-2p)^k + \frac{(-1)^k(p-2)}{2(p-1)} - \frac{(1-2p)^k (p-2)}{2(p-1)}
$$
I think.

Comment: check my answer out , please .

Answer (score 0):

Another method using the coupled equations,

Let $X_k = {(u_k\:v_k)}^T$, then $X_{k+1} = -A X_k$ with $A$ the following matrix:

\begin{pmatrix} 
p+1 & p-2 \\
p & p-1 
\end{pmatrix}

Diagonalize the matrix with it characteristic polynomial $(X+p+1)(X+p-1) + p(p-2)$ and apply the change of basis:

$X_{k+1} = -A X_k = -P^{-1}DP X_k$, then $X_k$ is a geometric sequence.

It suffice to compute $A^k = P^{-1}D^kP$ to obtain $X_k=(-1)^kP^{-1}D^kP X_0$.